# How can I convert OsStr to &[u8]/Vec<u8> on Windows?

Tags: string, rust

I'm trying to persistent raw OS file names to storage, so I need to get the raw bytes of an `OsStr`.

It seems possible to call [`as_bytes()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/ffi/trait.OsStrExt.html#tymethod.as_bytes) on *nix platforms, but that isn't defined on MS Windows.

Is there a portable way to convert `OsStr` to bytes?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include 
the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary 
to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem 
statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and 
Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi What is unclear about the question? This isn't about debugging...

Comment: > **must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it**

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi Notice the passage you quoted is preceded with "Questions seeking debugging help". This isn't the case here. OP is looking for a function that behaves like `as_bytes` but works on windows. There is nothing to fix, hence it makes no sense to ask for a MCVE.

Comment: @Alec I'm asking to clarify "does not work".

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi The function is not defined for windows. As in does not exist. It is OS specific. I'll clarify the question for the OP.

Comment: There is always [this crate](https://docs.rs/os-str-generic/0.2.0/os_str_generic/index.html). But you'll need to figure out the conversion from `u16` to `u8` since windows is UTF-16.

Comment: OsStr itself uses WTF-8 (i.e., UTF-8 with surrogates) internally, even on Windows, which is an implementation detail. The only way to get the raw bytes is to do an unsafe transmute from an OsStr to a &[u8], but this could not be guaranteed to always work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The point of `OsStr` is that its very representation is OS-specific. The implementation is somewhat convoluted for technical reasons ([@Shepmaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43093946/1600898) provides more details), but you can think of it like this:

- on POSIX systems, `OsStr` boils down to `&[u8]`, because POSIX functions accept and return byte strings;
- on Windows, `OsStr` can be thought of as an `&[u16]`, because Win32 Unicode functions accept and return strings as arrays of 16-bit units.

Since native Windows APIs accept sequences of 16-bit "wide characters"<sup>1</sup>, that is what `OsStr` is designed to store. While an `OsStr` *could* be converted to bytes inasmuch anything can be converted to bytes, such representation is not useful because those bytes would be neither meaningful to the user nor to the system. This is why `OsStr` does not provide a method to retrieve the contents as bytes on Windows. However, it does provide `OsStr::encode_wide()` that iterates over the underlying `u16` values which *is* useful in Win32. In the other direction, `OsString::from_wide()` can be used to create an `OsString` from a slice of `u16` values.

It is up to you to decide how your persistence layer will deal with this difference between platforms. What Rust's `OsStr` provides are the necessary **tools** to implement the round-trip, but the code will necessarily differ between platforms. For example, serde resolves the difference by [effectively treating](https://serde.rs/data-model.html#mapping-into-the-data-model) as `enum OsString { Unix(Vec<u8>), Windows(Vec<u16>) }`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Windows wide character strings are sometimes described as UTF-16 because that is how they are interpreted at a higher level, but this is not correct for *all* OS strings. A Windows file name can contain pairs of `u16` values that are *not* valid UTF-16, and still be usable. This is why it's not possible to represent Windows strings as bytes by e.g. converting them to UTF-8.

Comment: IIRC, Windows and Java actually use UCS-2.

Comment: @Shepmaster Yeah, that's quite correct, but the very term UCS-2 can generate confusion which I wanted to avoid in the answer. UCS-2 is obsolete and is no longer considered an encoding of Unicode (see [page 900 here](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode9.0.0/appC.pdf#G1823). It comes from a time when Unicode was constrained to the BMP, and the consortium has good reasons to discourage its use. The [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#unicode) is careful not to name the encoding UCS-2, preferring to refer to UTF-16 and the BMP.

Comment: `OsStr` can't possibly be anything other than a UTF-8 superset, because Rust supports no-allocation zero-cost conversion of `&str` to `&Path`, and `&Path` to `&OsStr`, so every valid `&str` memory representation must be a valid `&OsStr`, which wouldn't hold true for UCS-2.

Comment: @Kornel Yes, WTF16 is used on Windows internally, but AFAIK it is not exposed in the API.

Comment: Not WTF-16, but WTF-8, which is UTF-8 with extra sequences for broken surrogate pairs. The whole point is that Rust has exposed this fact, and made the API impossible to implement with an 16-bit internal representation of `OsStr`. `OsStr` is de-facto guaranteed to always be internally implemented as UTF-8 with hacks (it has to be `&[u8]`, it can't be `&[u16]`), as otherwise it couldn't satisfy required `AsRef` implementations.

Comment: @Kornel Thanks for the clarification, but the key question is can you access the underlying WTF-8 data using the public API? The OP was concerned with converting `OsStr` to bytes.

Comment: These answers are wrong but reflect how badly broken Rust is. Consider trying to iterate over a directory whose name came from running a Windows program ... Command::new(...).output().unwrap() .stdout() returns Vec<u8>, but std::fs::read_dir takes a std::path::Path, which is constructed from an OsStr. Good luck converting the former to the latter ... OsStrExt::from_bytes is only available on Unix. What's the point of an abstraction like OsString if it's not usable on every OS?

Comment: ... You can convert the Command output to a string via String::from_utf8_lossy, but that's just it ... it's lossy, so there are Windows command outputs that cannot be passed to Windows API's via Rust. "While an OsStr could be converted to bytes inasmuch anything can be converted to bytes, such representation is not useful because those bytes would be neither meaningful to the user nor to the system." -- sorry, but this is completely wrongheaded. I/O is byte streams -- you can't maintain Rust's abstractions externally; it's all just bytes.

Comment: @JimBalter That's exactly the problem, I/O is byte streams and Windows file names are not bytes, they're UCS-2 (masquerading as UTF-16). I agree that a public API for non-lossy conversion between path names and bytes would be useful, but it would need to be invented as a Rust-specific abstraction because Win32 itself doesn't provide one.

Comment: Of course Windows file names are bytes; everything is bytes. "a public API for non-lossy conversion between path names and bytes would be useful" -- it already exists, but it was made POSIX-only several years ago by people who don't understand the subject. Of course it's a Rust-specific abstraction ... because it's the Rust library we're talking about, not because of Win32. Every other "systems programming" language gets this right. If I run a command on Windows that prints a file name, the output is bytes, Command returns it as bytes, but Rust doesn't allow converting it back. Feh.

Comment: @JimBalter "Everything is bytes" - sure, but on Windows the bytes are UCS-2, so you cannot print the even an ASCII file name as "bytes" without garbling the output. On Windows you need to _encode_ the names, and you can't just use UTF-8 because UTF-8 can't represent all of UCS-2, by design (UCS-2 is obsolete). I agree it would be useful to have a way to format file names as bytes, but it's not simple. Such a solution might end up being Rust-specific, in the sense that it wouldn't work correctly (for weird enough file names) if the other command is not written in Rust.

Comment: I think you're ignoring most of what I wrote and repeating yourself, but this isn't a chat room and I've already typed more than enough. Have a good day. Over and out.

Comment: @JimBalter You don't seem to be offering a concrete suggestion here, except "just use bytes". Can you at least provide a reference for the other systems languages that get this right?

Answer (score 8):

There is no defined interface for getting  the bytes of an `OsStr` on Windows in Rust 1.16. The actual implementation of `OsStr` [delegates to system-specific code](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.16.0/src/libstd/ffi/os_str.rs#L18). On *nix, this is a [wrapper around a `Vec<u8>`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.16.0/src/libstd/sys/unix/os_str.rs#L21-L23); on Windows, this is a [wrapper around a `Wtf8Buf`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.16.0/src/libstd/sys/windows/os_str.rs#L20-L23). While `Wtf8Buf` is implemented with a `Vec<u8>`, that implementation detail is not exposed. More detail about WTF-8 is available [on its website](https://simonsapin.github.io/wtf-8/), which includes this quote, emphasis mine:

> On Windows (which uses potentially ill-formed UTF-16 in its APIs), the
>   Rust standard library uses WTF-8 internally for OS strings, but **does
>   not expose the WTF-8 byte sequences**.

The "problem" is that on different platforms, there's no unified concept of a "string" when it comes to passing it to an operating system interface. On *nix, *usually* interfaces accept something *almost* like UTF-8, except they don't handle embedded NUL values. On Windows, it depends on if you are calling the `W` or `A` variant of the API, although the `W` variant is strongly preferred.

This is made more difficult because libraries may also use different encodings from the OS. This is especially true if you use a C library created on *nix on Windows — it's almost guaranteed to take in a pseudo-UTF-8 string and then some sort of lossy transformation occurs to call the right underlying API.

Rust avoids all that by providing the opaque types `OsStr` and `OsString`.

---

If you need to pass an `OsStr` to a function that accepts UTF-8 data, you need to convert it to a `String` or `&str`, then you can get the bytes of that. If you need to pass it to a function that accepts a `LPCWSTR`, you first need to convert to a `Vec<u16>` and then pass the pointer to that buffer to the Windows API. You can see [an example of how Rust itself does this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.16.0/src/libstd/sys/windows/mod.rs#L98-L109).