# Clap raw bytes arguments

Tags: rust, clap

I would like to use raw byte argument with clap

For example `--raw $(echo -n -e 'B\x10CC\x01\xff')` will give me the following bytes array `[66, 16, 67, 67, 1, 239, 191, 189]` (using `to_string_lossy().to_bytes()`).

Is there a way to get exact bytes array using clap?

EDIT

```
let cmd = Command::new(
        env!("CARGO_CRATE_NAME")
    ).bin_name(
        env!("CARGO_CRATE_NAME")
    ).arg(
        Arg::new("raw").long("raw").takes_value(true).allow_invalid_utf8(true)
    );
    let matches = cmd.get_matches();


    match matches.value_of_os("raw") {
        Some(s) => {
            match s.to_str() {
                Some(s3) => {
                    let v2: &[u8] = s3.as_bytes();
                    println!("OsStr(bytes):{:?}", v2);
                },
                None => {},
            }

            let s2 = s.to_string_lossy();
            println!("string_from_OsString:{}", s2);

            let v3: &[u8] = s2.as_bytes();
            println!("OsString.to_lossy(bytes):{:?}", v3);
        },
        None => {},
    }
```

return for input --raw `$(echo -n -e 'B\x10CC\x01\xff')`

```
string_from_OsString:BCC�
OsString.to_lossy(bytes):[66, 16, 67, 67, 1, 239, 191, 189]
```

Thank you

Comment: Please provide your existing code. Do you have any errors? What have you tried?

Comment: Try the [`as_bytes()` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/ffi/trait.OsStrExt.html#tymethod.as_bytes) directly on the `OsStr`.

Comment: @isaactfa notably that is not available on Windows. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43093946/847382

Comment: @PitaJ That is notable! Though the use of `echo -e` leads me to believe OP is using some sort of Unix shell.

Comment: I have updated the post with code and response.
The use of as_bytes is not working.
I would like to obtain the ascii bytes values as it's possible using golang or python.

Comment: Please provide a minimal executable example, your example lacks a `main()` and the necessary `use` statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clap` is platform agnostic and therefore uses abstractions like `OsString` (which is the type of your `s` variable).

There seems to be no generic `as_bytes()` method attached to `OsString`, because not on every operating system `OsString` *is* actually a raw bytes array.

Here is a lot more discussion about this very topic: [How can I convert OsStr to &[u8]/Vec<u8> on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43083544/how-can-i-convert-osstr-to-u8-vecu8-on-windows)

So to solve your problem, it seems necessary that you narrow your compatibility down to a specific operating system. In your case, it seems that you are using `Unix`. Which is great, because for `Unix`, such a method [does exist](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/ffi/trait.OsStrExt.html)!

Here you go:

```
use clap::{Arg, Command};
use std::os::unix::ffi::OsStrExt;

fn main() {
    let cmd = Command::new(env!("CARGO_CRATE_NAME"))
        .bin_name(env!("CARGO_CRATE_NAME"))
        .arg(
            Arg::new("raw")
                .long("raw")
                .takes_value(true)
                .allow_invalid_utf8(true),
        );
    let matches = cmd.get_matches();

    match matches.value_of_os("raw") {
        Some(s) => {
            println!(".as_bytes(): {:?}", s.as_bytes());
        }
        None => {}
    }
}
```

```
.as_bytes(): [66, 16, 67, 67, 1, 255]
```

Note that the `use std::os::unix::ffi::OsStrExt;` will add the `.as_bytes()` functionality to `OsString`, but will fail to compile on non-unix systems.